# Touch action on a Sprite in cocos2d

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, css-sprites

I want to make an action in my sprites when they get touched, this is the action method:

```
-(void) spriteEffect
{
    CCSprite *actionEffect = avatar;
    id jump = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1 position: ccp(0, 0) height:50 jumps:1];
    id sequence = [CCSequence actions: jump, nil];
    [actionEffect runAction:sequence];
}
```

now, my problem is, that I don't know how to make the touch action connect with the sprite; should I use this?

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

Msp are in a .png image with a .plist assigned.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 1) 
    {
        // Add Your Action
    }

}
```

**OR**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SpriteThouch)];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

and call method `SpriteThouch`

```
-(void)SpriteThouch
{
  // code here 

}
```

Comment: I select sprites to play a game, I just want to add an action when they get touched, just to make them more nicer, but NO when they are choosen, look at this  image and you will realise
http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/3/35/Character_Selection_MKW2!!.png

imagine you pick Luigi, luigi appears down there, and i want to add an action that make that luigi to jump

Comment: When I use 'UITapGestureRecognizer' it todls me that CCSprite may not respond to 'addGestureRecognizer.'

Comment: first create object of CCSprite and then initialize and then after add ..may be solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks :) nice to hear good advices; but I've already initialize the CCSprite, I call it avatar, the one in the method. :/ Where should I utilize/put the UITapGestureRecognizer? in the initWithMenuScene?

Comment: [[[CCSprite sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:gr];

Comment: Now it's says: Instance method '-sharedDirector' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: check edited anser...[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:gr];

Comment: And now it says 'openGLView' is deprecated :(

Comment: should I add this to my method?:

-(void) SpriteThouch **(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer**

Comment: you need to put more code here :) if my answer helpful for you then you can give me +1 or accept :) thanks :)

Comment: welcome ....i think put this question as new question with more information & code :) any ways thanks to u:)

Comment: Hey Patel, one more question. Where should i put the UITapGestureRecognizer? in the initWithMenuScene? where? maybe that is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I use CCNode+SFGestureRecognizers.h (https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/CCNode-SFGestureRecognizers) to add gestures to my sprites.

So all that you need to do is:

- import CCNode+SFGestureRecognizers.h
- add sprite: CCSprite *button = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:....
- add code for sprite

  button.isTouchEnabled = YES;

  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:target action:selector];

  [button addGestureRecognizer:tap];

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [CCMenuItemImage](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.9.0-beta/interface_c_c_menu_item_image.html) when I want to handle **simple** sprite touches :

Use the following method to create the menu item:

```
itemFromNormalImage:selectedImage:target:selector:
```

As you can see you can pass an image of the menu item (i.e sprite image) , pass the target (usually self which implements the action) and of course the method (selector) which will get called when the menu item has been touched.

If you need more help on that let me know...

Comment: The thing is that I'm working with a .png and a .plist where all the sprites are there, so I cant use a single .png for every image; I have to make all it one move...

Comment: What do you mean by all sprites are there ?

Comment: I have a .png with all the sprites situated there, something like this: http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/147/e/5/godzilla_domination_sprites_by_blzofozz-d3h277l.png

Comment: ohhhh.. Yeah now I understand. Hmm ... You could read each one and create a menuitem for each. And I think a menu is the solution for your problem as you just need some buttons to be pushed right ?

Comment: select sprites to play a game, I just want to add an action when they get touched, just to make them more nicer, but NO when they are choosen, look at this image and you will realise http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/3/35/Character_Selection_MKW2!!.png  imagine you pick Luigi, luigi appears down there, and i want to add an action that make that luigi to jump –

Comment: when you say jump you mean an animated jump using a sprite sheet or just make the entire image jump ?

Comment: I mean this: 
-(void) spriteEffect
{
    CCSprite *actionEffect = avatar;
    id jump = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1 position: ccp(0, 0) height:50 jumps:1];
    id sequence = [CCSequence actions: jump, nil];
    [actionEffect runAction:sequence];
}

Comment: Than you can easily run this action on a CCMenuItemImage object as it inherits from CCNode and has all the needed properties for a jump.